# How to skip the empty pages when reading MS Word document with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, text-extraction, winforms-interop

I have an application that reads the text from MS Word document with the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word like this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs         = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, true, ref miss,
                                                                                      ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
                                                                                      ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
                                                                                      ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
            string totaltext = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < docs.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
            {
                totaltext += " \r\n " + docs.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.ToString();
            }           
            docs.Close();
            word.Quit();
```

I need the value of totaltext after the "for".But sometimes, when the MS Word document have only 2 pages with content and 100 empty ones it is extremely slow because it is reading the empty pages too.
I am trying to find a way to skip the empty pages.

Comment: Is extracting the text all you're trying to accomplish or is there anything else?

Comment: Thats all I am trying to do.

Comment: And is using Word Interop a requirement or just the way you chose to do it? I'm asking because, even if you'll solve this thing, Interop is incredibly slow.